# WordPress error with require_once

Tags: wordpress, include

I have this error in my wordpress, on frontend and dashboard:

> Warning: require_once(includes/theme-widgets.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/masqueci/public_html/functions.php on line 2
>
> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'includes/theme-widgets.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/masqueci/public_html/functions.php on line 2

The problem is that I try to delete this line, rename the file, delete the all theme and delete wp-admin and wp-include and upload it again. But the error continue. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Disable all the plugins and swap to the default theme TwentyTwelve/Thirteen, does it still happens?

Comment: No, i cant acces to dashboard. I delete the theme, but the error continue...

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are using a worng reletive path to the file wanted.

Try on using:

```
$filePath = get_bloginfo('template_url'); // this line gets you the path to the current theme.
$filePath .= 'includes/theme-widgets.php'; // now we add the relative path to your file
require_once($filePath); // now we place the hole thing inside the 'require_once' function.
```

now you can minimize the code by:

```
require_once(get_bloginfo('template_url').'includes/theme-widgets.php');
```

what was originally responded by the function was that it was trying on going to:
`public_html/includes/theme-widgets.php` which did not exist while your path was:
`public_html/wp-content/themes/{theme_name}/includes/theme-widgets.php`

The code i have provided before should do the job for you :)

Comment: The problem is that a i have delete the theme but it continue give me an error, how is this posible?

Comment: can you tell me more what you have been trying to do?

Comment: I try to delete  the line, the file and the all theme. I delete the wp-admin and wp-include and reupload. A dont know what else can i do..

Comment: you are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I only want to fix this problem

Comment: it was not made by you?

Comment: i have fix it. In dreamweaver the functions file had been copied to wordpress root. Therefore, though i delete the file it gave me an path error,and so although it was deleted because it were on root. Excuse my english please, and thanks!

Comment: i'm glad to hear that is has been fixed :) have a nice day !